# Overwrite Postgres now() function

Tags: postgresql

In my test database, I want to override `now()` in Postgres, so I can travel to a certain point in time. I'd like to override it like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA if not exists override;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION override.now()
RETURNS timestamp with time zone
AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN pg_catalog.now() + COALESCE(
  NULLIF(current_setting('timecop.offset_in_seconds', true), '')::integer, 0
) * interval '1 second';
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT;
SET search_path TO DEFAULT;
SELECT set_config('search_path', 'override,' || current_setting('search_path'), false);
```

To enable it, I call

```
SET timecop.offset_in_seconds = 3600 -- 1 hour ahead
```

To disable it, I call

```
RESET timecop.offset_in_seconds
```

The problem is, that Postgres somehow doesn't use the function:

```
app_test=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2022-12-04 10:22:26.824469+00
(1 row)

app_test=# SET timecop.offset_in_seconds = 3600;
SET
app_test=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2022-12-04 10:22:34.481502+00
(1 row)
```

Looking at the `now()` method itself, I seems like the search path searches in `pg_catalog` before the `override` schema:

```
app_test=# \df+ now
                                                                                        List of functions
   Schema   | Name |     Result data type     | Argument data types | Type | Volatility | Parallel |  Owner   | Security | Access privileges | Language | Source code |       Description
------------+------+--------------------------+---------------------+------+------------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+-------------+--------------------------
 pg_catalog | now  | timestamp with time zone |                     | func | stable     | safe     | postgres | invoker  |                   | internal | now         | current transaction time
```

So, how could I move my overwritten `now()` BEFORE the `pg_catalog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_catalog` is *always* on the search path, but you can opt not to have it in the beginning:

```
SET search_path = override, pg_catalog;
```

Comment: thank you so much, that saved me some headache!